# "File in use" message doesn't appear when file is open by someone else

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-sharing

When Excel file is shared and someone opens it for editing, another person opening it should see a message like below:

[image]

In my company we started blocking shares which have "Everyone" group added, so we can only use advanced sharing and then remove "Everyone" and add specific users and groups.

Since that the message doesn't appear, but instead of it everyone can edit file and save it without changes made by others. Now I get message like that only when I'm owner of the file in Windows system, but I would like it to work like that for all users. Is is possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The message will only show up if you try to edit the file while someone is viewing it. If you don't save the changes then no window will pop up. Everybody should be getting the message if there is an instance of it somewhere on the network if changes are attempted to be made. You could possibly work around this by making sure the file is always open somewhere and in your control, or set the file to read-only for people in the "Everyone" group.